# transfering data from multiple tables from MSSQL to H2DB and applying formulas to data

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, jdbc, h2

I have four tables in MSSQL and I want to transfer data from MSSQL to H2DB using a join table query which joins all four tables .
means I want to transfer data from multiple tables from MSSQL to H2DB

and before transferring those data i have to perform some calculations on this data and want this in additional columns of H2 database.

.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried transferring formulas before
But you can use this useful tool to transfer data from SQL Server to db2 and of course test the ability to transfer the formula

https://sourceforge.net/projects/opendbcopy/